# Javascript Regular Expression to replace only outside of a match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to replace but limit to a certain portion of the string i basically want to leave anything inside double ` untouched and only replace out side of these conditions

```
var message = "this is my :) `funky :)` string with a funky `goal :D` live is good :D";

var map = {
    "<3": "\u2764\uFE0F",
    "</3": "\uD83D\uDC94",
    ":D": "\uD83D\uDE00",
    ":)": "\uD83D\uDE03",
    ":-)": "\uD83D\uDE03",
    ";)": "\uD83D\uDE09",
    ":(": "\uD83D\uDE12",
    ":p": "\uD83D\uDE1B",
    ";p": "\uD83D\uDE1C",
    ":'(": "\uD83D\uDE22",
    ":S": "\ud83d\ude1f",
    ":$": "\ud83d\ude33",
    ":@": "\ud83d\ude21"
};
for (var i in map) {
    var regex = new RegExp(i.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1'), 'gim');
    message = message.replace(regex, map[i]);
}
```

The expected output i want is

```
this is my \uD83D\uDE0f `funky :)` string with a funky `goal :D` live is good \uD83D\uDE00
```

Comment: Edited as i realised my bad

Comment: ive used `\`([\s\S]*?)\`` to try and match, but that only matches inside, i want pretty much the opposite

Comment: where does `i` come from?

Comment: Sorry i realised i missed this from the extracted code added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a regular expression that alternates between all the `.keys` of the `map`, escaping the keys first so that the characters with a special meaning in a regular expression (like `$`) get parsed as *literal characters* rather than special regex characters.

Also alternate with a pattern that matches a backtick followed by non-backtick characters, followed by another backtick - that way all backtick-enclosed substrings will be matched as well.

Call `.replace` on the input string with the constructed patter and use a replacer function. If the match starts with a backtick, then the match is something you don't want to modify at all, so just return the match. Otherwise, the match is one of the keys of `map`, so return the associated value at that key in `map`:

```js
const message = "this is my :) `funky :)` string with a funky `goal :D` live is good :D";
const map = {
    "<3": "\u2764\uFE0F",
    "</3": "\uD83D\uDC94",
    ":D": "\uD83D\uDE00",
    ":)": "\uD83D\uDE03",
    ":-)": "\uD83D\uDE03",
    ";)": "\uD83D\uDE09",
    ":(": "\uD83D\uDE12",
    ":p": "\uD83D\uDE1B",
    ";p": "\uD83D\uDE1C",
    ":'(": "\uD83D\uDE22",
    ":S": "\ud83d\ude1f",
    ":$": "\ud83d\ude33",
    ":@": "\ud83d\ude21"
};
const escape = str => str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
const backtickPattern = '`[^`]*`';


const pattern = new RegExp(
  backtickPattern + '|' + Object.keys(map)
    .map(escape)
    .join('|'),
  'g'
);
const output = message.replace(pattern, match => {
  if (match.startsWith('`')) {
    // backtick, don't perform any replacements:
    return match;
  }
  return map[match];
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: that seemed to replace all of the elements 

result was 

this is my  `funky ` string with a funky `goal ` live is good 

Comment: Check it again - the check if the match `startsWith` a backtick should take care of the backtick-enclosed substrings